# RTP delay in concurrent calls

Tags: webrtc, sip, voip, wireshark, rtp

This the call scenario:

DTLS=true, earlymedia=false

- Call A: make a first web to web call, established ok, call media ok. Call ongoing
- Call B: make a second web to web call, established ok, call media ok. Call ongoing.
- Call C: make a third web to web call, it is established with media delayed of 3 seconds. Call ongoing.

During the time the call C is established, the other two calls A and B starts having too a 3 seconds media delay.

When Call C is hang up, after 10/15 seconds the calls A and B returns to media path without delays.

When I check Wireshark RTP streams, seeing that 0 jitter and 0 delta. also I checked the graph it showed that a pike but couldn't figure out the relationship.

[image]

How can I investigate further?

Comment: if it is in the browser you might want to use chrome's chrome://webrtc-internals to gather more data about the internal state. https://testrtc.com/webrtc-internals-documentation/ provides some documentation

Comment: I do, and share results